# how to create an excel formula with vlookup and if argument

Tags: excel, if-statement, formatting, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to create a formula that looks up for a specific text in the range in provide or column and if it finds the text, write that text or the text in the right column in another cell. I am currently using this formula:

```
=LOOKUP("Haider",O11:O16,E1:E6)
```

However even when it can not find Haider in the range O11:O16, it still writes the text in the column E1:E6 to the cell in which I wrote the formula.

Also, as there would be only a single word in the entire column at one time, you 
could help me with a formula that simply copies that word to a cell of my choice.

Another question is that how can I combine this with conditional formatting? For example, if I want to find the text and if it is found the range I specify, it should turn another cell into red or any color.

Comment: Your question is really not clear.  Specifically for `LOOKUP` it returns the last value if there was no match.  An `INDEX-MATCH` formula is better when you want to not return values on missing searches.  `=INDEX(E1:E6, MATCH("Haider",O11:O16,0))`.  The `0` specifically tells it to only return a result on an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is answered in the comment from Byron Wall.

For the second part of the question, if you want to find the first or only cell containing text in a range, the  formula is:-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*", O11:O16, 1,FALSE),"")
```

If you want to find the first or only cell containing anything, the formula is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(O11:O16,MATCH(TRUE,O11:O16<>"",0)),"")
```

but you have to enter it as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

For the last part of the question, supposing you wanted to highlight the cell in E1:E6 corresponding to the cell in O11:O16 containing "Haider", you would need the formula:-

```
=$O11="Haider"
```

(this compares E1 with O11, E2 with O12 etc. because of relative addressing)

Highlight E1 to E6.

Go to 'Conditional Formatting'.

Select 'New Rule' and 'Use a formula...' , enter the formula and choose a fill colour in the Format option.

Comment: Thanks for reply. however there is a problem that when Haider is not found, the cell reads N/A. Can't it be empty or read 'full'.

Another question is that can't i omit the entire O11:O16 part so that if Haider is found in the range it replies with either Haider or Full.

Comment: kindly answer this as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by omitting the range, but I'll put an IFERROR into the answer so that it shows a blank when there is nothing in the range.